# What are the drawbacks to deploying web applications to Tomcat using the filesystem rather than an EAR file?

Tags: tomcat, devops

Since Tomcat just unzips the <strike>EAR</strike> WAR to the filesystem to serve the app, what is the benefit of using an <strike>EAR</strike> WAR and what are the drawbacks to just pushing a filesystem to the Tomcat webapps filesystem?

Comment: Tomcat does not support EARs, did you mean WARs?

Comment: I guess you should write WAR instead of EAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat supports WAR but not EAR. Anyways , I think your question is about why we normally deploy the application that is packaged as a single WAR rather than the exploded WAR (i.e exploded deployment).

The main advantages for me are :

- It is more easy to handle the deployment when you just need to deploy one file versus deploying many files in the exploded WAR deployment.
- Because there is only one file get deployed , we can always make sure the application is running in a particular version. If we allow to deploy individual files and someone just update several files to other version , it is difficult to tell what is the exact version that the application is running.

There are already some discussion about such topics before , you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703901/java-webapp-deployment-explode-or-not-to-explode) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906881/advantages-disadvantages-to-exploded-war-files) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

EAR (Enterprise Application aRchive) **`is not supported by Tomcat`** (web container).

As you have written Tomcat I guess you are asking about WAR and extracted/exploded WAR.

- Normally WAR file extracted once it start deploying
- You can make change in exploded folder, but war will not be deployed again as it is already extracted and changes will be applied
- Can be deployed even without WAR(extracted folder, will save some seconds)
- Deployment can be easy with ONE file - Advantage of WAR
- if deployed extracted, Versions of application can not be identified as you can make changes in already extracted file system - Disadvantage of Extracted

Answer (score 0):

I see some benefits, if you deploy a single war-file

- If you have multiple environments (ex. test and prod), you have just to move one single file from one Server to another
- If you want to enshure, that you deploy the correct file, you can calculate a hash-sum from that single file
- You allwas have an original version: Sometimes you have to edit a file in the exploded war (Try to avoid this). If you have done this and you want to roll it back, you just delete the exploded-war-folder and the tomcat uses the war file
- you can use the manager-app to deploy the app via your browser so that you don't need access to the server

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous and unclear to me, as it's hard to understand what you try to clarify; however, let's take your points one by one.

---

> Since Tomcat just unzips the EAR to the filesystem to serve the app..

Tomcat can not explode and deploy EAR files, because it does not implement entirety of Jakarta (formerly - Java) EE specification; EAR, however, is an "Enterprise Archive", i.e. an Enterprise Java Application archive, which doesn't fit into subspecifications only.

Rather, Tomcat is a Web Server (often referred as Servlet Container, Servlet Engine, Web Container), which implements:

1. Servlet API;
2. JSP;
3. EL (Expression Language);
4. Web Socket;
5. Jakarta Annotations;
6. Jakarta Authorization,

and all these are sub-specifications of Java/Jakarta EE.

> what is the benefit of using an EAR?

EAR is a fully-blown Enterprise (Application) Archive, which brings much more, that just Servlet, JSP, and etc.

> what are the drawbacks to just pushing a filesystem to the Tomcat webapps filesystem?

Nothing, generally speaking. `webapps` is a default folder where Tomcat will usually try to look for a web applications, that are expected to be `.war` files.